# How to group array items as a specific typescript type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

lets say I have this array:

```
  const dataUse = [
    { group: 'z', name: 'hello' },
    { group: 'z', name: 'hello2' },
    { group: 'z', name: 'hello3' },
    { group: 'x', name: 'hello1' },
    { group: 'x', name: 'hello2' }
  ];
```

I want to group it on group and I do so by:

group func:

```
  const groupBy = <T, K extends keyof any>(arr: T[], key: (i: T) => K) =>
    arr.reduce((groups, item) => {
      (groups[key(item)] ||= []).push(item);
      return groups;
    }, {} as Record<K, T[]>);
```

calling:

```
  const grouped = groupBy(dataUse, (i) => i.group);
```

result:

```
{
x: Array
z: Array
}
```

Problem:

I need to be able to access the properties and in my case x and z are dynamic and will never have the same name. So I thought that I need to group my data as a specific container type:

```
type GroupContainer = {
  group: string;
  items: Array<MyListObj>;
};
```

Desiered output would be:

```
[
{Group: 'x', items:Array}
{Group: 'z', items:Array}
]
```

The helper func does turns this into records and Im not sure how to turn it into GroupContainer

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will give us an array with key-value pairs, so we can just map over them and use them for our object:

```
Object.entries(grouped).map(([group, items]) => ({ group, items }))
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nngpam)